# Jquery fadeToggle - hides and comes back?

Tags: jquery

We have the following script:

```
$('#toggledot1').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.dotclick:visible').fadeOut();
$('#parkdaycare').fadeToggle();
});
$('#toggledot2').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.dotclick:visible').fadeOut();
$('#displaysales').fadeToggle();
});
```

What this does, is clicking on the div, toggles the other div to show/hide whilst also hiding the other divs. Problem with this, is that if you click on the same div again, it fades out and then fades straight back in.

Solution?

Comment: Attach a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: Add HTML and jsFiddle the code please. Until then this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$('.dotclick:visible').fadeOut();` fades out the current item when you click again which will trigger the `fadeToggle` to display it back again

The solution is to omit the current target element from the `$('.dotclick:visible')` selector

```
$('#toggledot1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dotclick:visible').not('#parkdaycare').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    $('#parkdaycare').stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
});
$('#toggledot2').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dotclick:visible').not('#displaysales').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    $('#displaysales').stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Without HTML I think you solved this via the process of elimination. Well done.

Comment: Perfect- thankyou, and sorry for my lack of explanation with my question